# Vedis KeyError при попытке извлечь данные

Tags: python, redis

Есть два статических метода - один данные записывает, другой извлекает

```
@staticmethod
def insert(key, data, d1=None, d2=None):
    datenow = str(date.today())
    with Vedis(db_file) as db:
        d = json.dumps({datenow: {data: {'e1': d1, 'e2': 
                                            d2}}})
        db[user] = d
```

И с этим все ок, если вызвать print(db[user]), он выводит записанные данные

```
@staticmethod
def get_hour(key):
    with Vedis(db_file) as db:
        return db[user]
```

А этот метод возвращает исключение KeyError, битый час уже голову ломаю, где я допустил ошибку?

Comment: `json.loads(db)` сделайте он у вас просто строку выводит

Comment: Переменная user чему равна? Если у вас ячейка с названием "user", то обращаться к ней надо как к имени("user"), а не к переменной(user)